# Highchart renderer path issue in IE8

Tags: jquery, css, highcharts

I have been using

```
chart.renderer.path(['M', 12, 0, 'L', 6, 12, 'L', 18, 12, 'Z']).attr({
    'stroke-width' : 2,
    'fill' : 'black',
    'transform' : "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")"        
  }).add();
```

to draw triangle path over the chart and move to require position by using Translate attribute.

But In IE8, the transform attribute is being ignored (the triangle appears in the top left corner), but it works fine in FF, Chrome etc. Is that the problem with CSS3 support issue?

Is there any work around to fix this issue?

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Legacy IE doesn't support the transform attribute directly. Instead, use the translate method like so:

```
chart.renderer.path(['M', 12, 0, 'L', 6, 12, 'L', 18, 12, 'Z']).attr({
    'stroke-width' : 2,
    'fill' : 'black'
  })
  .translate(x, y)
  .add();
```

There are also specific translateX and translateY attributes that you can use, which also work with .animate() in addition to .attr().

Edit: here's a live demo: http://jsbin.com/iwocow/1/edit